# pybind11 - memcpy array of values to numpy array

Tags: python, c++, numpy, pybind11

I have a vector of vector of doubles which I want to return as a 2D numpy array using pybind11.

I am looking for an efficient way to copy the data from each inner vector to the appropriate strided point in the numpy array.

Below is an example which works, but it iterates over every element, setting 1 double at a time:

```cpp
#include <pybind11/numpy.h>
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <vector>

namespace py = pybind11;

using PyValues = py::array_t<double, py::array::c_style | py::array::forcecast>;

PyValues vals()
{
    using Row = std::vector<double>;
    using Rows = std::vector<Row>;

    Rows rows = {
        { 1., 11.1, 101 },
        { 2., 12.2, 102 },
        { 3., 13.3, 103 },
        { 4., 14.4, 104 },
    };

    const std::size_t num_rows = rows.size();
    const std::size_t num_cols = rows[0].size();

    PyValues values = PyValues({num_rows,num_cols});

    auto mu = values.mutable_unchecked();

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < num_rows; i++)
        for (std::size_t j = 0; j < num_cols; j++)
            mu(i, j) = rows[i][j];

    return values;
}
```

I am looking to replace this nested loop:

```cpp
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < num_rows; i++)
    for (std::size_t j = 0; j < num_cols; j++)
        mu(i, j) = rows[i][j];
```

Looking at the internals of `pybind11::numpy`, I can see that `mutable_unchecked` returns an object which has the following member:

```cpp
/// Mutable pointer access to the data at the given indices.
template <typename... Ix>
T *mutable_data(Ix... ix) 
{
    return &operator()(ssize_t(ix)...);
}
```

As such, I tried to do the following:

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < num_rows; ++i)
    std::memcpy(mu.mutable_data(i,0), rows[i].data(), num_cols);
```

However, this is not working as I expected, instead my numpy array has garbage in it, so presumably my access indices are incorrect?

I've played around with swapping the indices to no avail.

How can I do a block copy of each of my inner vectors into my numpy array?

Comment: This was a simple bug! I was copying `num_cols` *bytes*, instead of `num_cols` *doubles*! The fix is: `std::memcpy(mu.mutable_data(i,0), rows[i].data(), num_cols * sizeof(double));`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was a silly bug

Comment: Voting to close your own question? Just delete it...